# Creating a KVM on Ubuntu 14.04 host fails

Tags: command-line, kvm-virtualization

I am trying this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cloud-images-and-uvtool.html

```
$ uvt-simplestreams-libvirt sync release=trusty arch=amd64
bogdanbiv@bivub1404:~$ time uvt-kvm create secondtest release=trusty

real    0m0.673s
user    0m0.127s
sys     0m0.050s

# although last command takes less than 1 second the next command proves 
# the former actually performed something
bogdanbiv@bivub1404:~$ uvt-kvm create secondtest release=trusty 
uvt-kvm: error: libvirt: storage volume 'secondtest.qcow' exists already

bogdanbiv@bivub1404:~$ uvt-kvm wait secondttest --insecure
uvt-kvm: error: libvirt: Domain not found: no domain with matching name 'secondttest'
```

So what's wrong here? These are exact commands from the Ubuntu documentation - I don't see any difference so I assume something's up.

I had generated a RSA key before creating my VMs.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, timing a command via `time` doesn't mean that its effects are undone after the command. So

```
time uvt-kvm create secondtest release=trusty
```

creates `secondtest`, and then you try to create it again:

```
uvt-kvm create secondtest release=trusty
```

which obviously fails, since the domain (and its associated image) already exists.

In the third command, you made a typo: `secondttest` instead of `secondtest`. So it should be:

```
uvt-kvm wait secondtest --insecure
```

Comment: OK, I definetly missed the double tt: `secondttest`. Will try to fix it and come back to this issue.

Comment: There is a typo in the docs https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/cloud-images-and-uvtool.html